# Eclipse cant see file

Tags: eclipse

An Eclipse project was working perfectly fine then it cant find the file.  I switched to IntelliJ and it compiled wo complaints.  How can this happen in Eclipse?  Can anyone give insight our do I have to switch?  (Eclipse, 2020-06, pass tests on the ssd, no error before or since)

[image]

Comment: You've done a **File**-> **Refresh** of one of its parent folders?

Comment: In Eclipse it's the package in the source folder _taedi > src/main/java > com.example.ta_edi.repository_ which is visible in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `taedi\src\main\java\com\example\ta_edi\repository` shown in screenshot in the Windows File Explorer is shown **in Eclipse** in the project *taedi* in the source folder *src/main/java* as the package *com.example.ta_edi.repository* that can also be seen in the screenshot:

- ***taedi > src/main/java > com.example.ta_edi.repository***

[image]